# Make element visible only for md sized devices

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

according to https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/display 
you can hide for a specific device size or range going up or down. But how would you show a div only for md sized devices? `hidden-lg-and-up hidden-sm-and-down` doesn't seem to work. concatenating `hidden-{x}-only` also does not seem to work.

Comment: `hidden-lg-and-up hidden-sm-and-down` should work. Can you reproduce non-working example?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Classes should work `class="hidden-lg-and-up hidden-sm-and-down"`

Or you could use `v-show="$vuetify.breakpoint.md"`

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odxXMB)

Comment: And how do I make the navigation drawer to only be available in smaller (mobile devices)?

Answer (score 6):

This also should work:

```
class="d-none d-md-flex d-lg-none"
```

[*Source*](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display).